# Printing current time after pressing enter

Tags: python, keyboard

Currently I am working on a keylogger as final project for my Python course. My idea is that when a user presses the return/enter button the time appears next to the previous typed text. Additionally, I would also like to stop the running when <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed. This is what I exactly mean:

```
www.gmail.com    02:20:50
www.google.com   02:21:42
stackoverflow    02:21:44
```

My code so far is something like this:

```py
import sys, termios, tty, os
from datetime import datetime

def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd , termios.TCSADRAIN , old_settings)
    return ch

file=open('register.txt','a')

while True:
    char = getch()
    if (char != "q"):
        file.write(char)
        if (char == "\n"):
            file.write('\t'+datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        print("Quit!")
        exit(0)
        file.close()
```

The problems here are although everything is successfully written in the file `register.txt` the time doesn't show up, and also I do not have any idea how to specify the character <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit the program

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The indentation of your code seems to be off.

Comment: I think the escape character is ascii, you can look it up on an ascii chart to figure out the binary representation then use the unichr() function to turn it into an char

Comment: You may have some luck with the [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) package